# Required field doesnt work in document libraries when we upload document in SharePoint 2010

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2010

When uploading a new document to the library, its a two step process. the document is considered "posted" as soon as step 1 is complete, but at that point in time none of the required fields has been uploaded yet, resulting in blank items showing.

Is there any way to stop upload document without filling required fields?

Thanks,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are 2 things you can do here: simple and more advanced.
Simple step is to make your fields "Required". After file has beed uploaded the form will pop up and user will have to fill out fields. Although this will not remove the file uploaded, but it will alert user to fill the fields.

Advanced way is to create event receiver or workflow which would actually remove the file after some period if required fields are not filled out. Workflow option could be easier to create and you can do that in Sharepoint Designer